# Finding the cause of system freezes - Fedora 39

Tags: fedora, freeze

On my main home computer I am running fedora 39. It was not originally running fedora 39, I've upgraded through at least 2 previous releases.
My problem is that every few hours my system either completely freezes, or I still can move the mouse around the screen but cannot do anything else. I cannot Ctrl-Alt-F* do drop to a console or anything like that, the only solution is to reboot.

I've been dealing with this problem for years, I have a feeling it is related to my graphics card (AMD Radeon 5700 now, but I had an AMD RX 480 in the past in the same computer with similar issues) , but I do not remember where that feeling comes from.

On each new boot, I take a peek at the end of `journalctl -k -b -1` but I don't see anything repeating there across occurrences, or anything that draws my attention.
I've recently updated my BIOS , but that doesn't seem to have improved anything

I wanted to say that I have kernel dumps enabled but nothing was ever recorded in /var/crash, however I now see I have a dump from november, looking through the dmesg log there I see

```
[ 7082.889352] BUG: kernel NULL pointer dereference, address: 0000000000000000
[ 7082.889361] #PF: supervisor read access in kernel mode
[ 7082.889366] #PF: error_code(0x0000) - not-present page
[ 7082.889370] PGD 0 P4D 0
[ 7082.889377] Oops: 0000 [#1] PREEMPT SMP NOPTI
[ 7082.889384] CPU: 11 PID: 0 Comm: swapper/11 Kdump: loaded Tainted: G           OE      6.5.9-200.fc38.x86_64 #1
[ 7082.889391] Hardware name: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd MS-7B00/B350 GAMING PRO CARBON (MS-7B00), BIOS 1.50 08/02/2017
[ 7082.889395] RIP: 0010:dc_stream_get_scanoutpos+0x5b/0x80 [amdgpu]
```

Maybe I've seen something like this in the past and that is why I suspect amdgpu. But again, I get freezes daily while apparently I only had a kernel bug once, months ago.

Thank you for reading so far, my question is: Does anyone have any ideas about how I can use software to track down the problem?
The only idea I have is to start swapping out hardware and see if that fixes anything, but that will cost and if I go down that way, I might as well upgrade my computer, which I'd like to not do for a few more years.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A while back on my Fedora machine I had exactly the same problem that you described. I would be using my computer then it would randomly freeze but usually the mouse would continue to move.

Initially I thought there was a problem with my Asus GeForce 8800 GT graphics card. However I removed the graphics card and I still had a these random freezes.

Nothing in the logs because I had to reboot.
I had a copy of [memtest86](https://www.memtest86.com/download.htm) so I decided to run a test on the memory and as soon as I started running Memtest86 I got a lot of errors.
So I was thinking that either one of my memory banks was badly seated or had developed an error.
I checked the seating of the memory sticks and everything was ok. However I noticed there as a lot of dust in one particular area of the memory stick nearest the the processor fan. I removed all the memory sticks and carefully vacuum cleaned the memory modules as well as the memory sticks and reseated the memory sticks back in the modules. From then on I've not had any random freezes.

Perhaps your problem is the same and running Memtest86 is very simple. Download the [right version if you boot from bios](https://www.memtest86.com/downloads/memtest86-4.3.7-iso.zip) as opposed to uefi. Let us know how it goes.

Comment: Thank you very much James for your reply. In the past I did use memtest86 and found no errors ; I've added more memory since but the behavior was there before as well.
Your post got me to stop suspecting my GPU (not that it is definitely not the case, but I was fixated on it). I found references online about some ryzen  cpus freezing in linux and people had various suggestions to change CPU c-states via boot parameters ; for now I've disabled c-state management in the bios and I am waiting for the next freeze (2 days no freeze so far).
Thanks again!